# CS193P assignment 2 Clear function

Tags: objective-c

Given this implementation:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)programStack
{
    if (_programStack == nil)
        _programStack = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    return _programStack;
}

- (id)program
{
    return [self.programStack copy];
}

+ (double)popOperandOffStack:(NSMutableArray *)stack
{
    double result = 0;

    id topOfStack = [stack lastObject];
    if (topOfStack)
        [stack removeLastObject];

    if ([topOfStack isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
        result = [topOfStack doubleValue];
    }
    else if ([topOfStack isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) 
    {
        NSString *operation = topOfStack;
        // C
        if ([operation isEqualToString:@"C"])
        {
            [stack removeAllObjects];
            return 0; 
        }
    }
}
```

Am I correct in assuming that the class method's call to [stack removeAllObjects] only affects a copy of a copy rather than removing all objects from the instance's _programStack ? How would you, from that class method, affect the instance's variable? Or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`[stack removeAllObjects];` will remove all objects from `stack`. If you call `+ (double)popOperandOffStack:(NSMutableArray *)stack` from an object, passing an instance variable as `stack`, then `popOperandOffStack:` operates on that instance variable and will remove all objects:

```
[[self class] popOperandOffStack:self.myInstanceArray]
```

If, on the other hand, you call `[[self class] popOperandOffStack:[self.myInstanceArray mutableCopy]]` it will operate on a copy.